# How to get UIScrollView vertical direction in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

How can I get the scroll/swipe direction for up/down in a VC?

I want to add a UIScrollView or something else in my VC that can see if the user swipes/scrolls up or down and then hide/show a `UIView` depending if it was an up/down gesture.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

If you use an `UIScrollView` then you can take benefit from the [`scrollViewDidScroll:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll:)  function. You need to save the last position (the `contentOffset`) it have and the update it like in the following way:

```
// variable to save the last position visited, default to zero
```

```
 private var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0

 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
         // move up
     }
     else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        // move down
     }

     // update the new position acquired
     self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
     print(lastContentOffset)
 }
```

There are other ways of doing it of course this is one of them.

Comment: Thanks it kinda works. But since scroll views has that bounce effect it fires both functions "didScrollUp" and "didScrollDown" back and forth a few times if I scroll all the way to the top or if I do a "pull to refresh" This results in my view toggeling between hidden/shown a few times. So maby I am off adding a swipe gesture to the scrollview/table view?

Comment: Be careful the `UITableView` has a `UIScrollView` inside!! If you have added another one you need to differentiate both

Comment: I am not adding another scrollview. I am using "override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)" But since the scrollview has that bounce effect it will toggle my view to be shown/hidden a few times. So am I better off adding a swipe gesture on my tableview?

Comment: This worked great for me when I wanted to hide a button when scrolling down, but show the button when scrolling up.  I solved the issue with bouncing/scrolling above/below scroll limits with the following that I have posted in a new reply below.

Comment: You must need to set bounces to false `self.scrollView.bounces = false` otherwise you'll get random event (mixed up and down movements) at the top or bottom location of scrollView.

Answer (score 78):

Victor's answer is great, but it's quite expensive, as you're always comparing and storing values. If your goal is to identify the scrolling direction instantly without expensive calculation, then try this **using Swift**:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let translation = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview)
    if translation.y > 0 {
        // swipes from top to bottom of screen -> down
    } else {
        // swipes from bottom to top of screen -> up
    }
}
```

And there you go. Again, if you need to track constantly, use Victors answer, otherwise I prefer this solution.

Comment: I used this one at first but be aware that it does not work if you trigger the scrolling programmatically, e.g. via `UIPageControl`

Comment: If I started with a downward scroll and change the direction to upwards without lifting my finger it won't detect the change until I pass the initial point at which I started. This is due to translation.y not resetting to zero until I lift my finger.

Comment: This won't work for the case where you tap on the status bar to automatically scroll at the top.

Answer (score 26):

I used Victor's answer with a minor improvement. When scrolling past the end or beginning of the scroll, and then getting the bounce back effect. I have added the constraint by calculating `scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height` and then limiting the `scrollView.contentOffset.y` range to be greater than 0 or less than `scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height`, no changes are made when bouncing back.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y && lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height {
        // move up
    } else if lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y && scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
        // move down
    }

    // update the new position acquired
    lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

Comment: This should have been marked as answer. Victor doesn't work on bounce effect.

Comment: Yea this solve my problem. Before i use scrollView.bound.size.height and it was little bugy with LazyVGrid.

Answer (score 19):

**For swift4**

Implement the `scrollViewDidScroll` method that detects when you pan gesture beyond a y-axis of 0:

```
    public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview).y > 0) {
        print("up")
    }
    else {
        print("down")
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 15):

I have tried every single response in this thread but none of them could provide a proper **solution for a tableView with bounce enabled**. So I just used parts of solutions along with some all-time classic boolean flag solution.

1) So, first of all you could use an enum for the scrollDirection:

```
enum ScrollDirection {
    case up, down
}
```

2) Set 3 new private vars to help us store lastOffset, scrollDirection and a flag to enable/disable the scroll direction calculation (helps us ignore the bounce effect of tableView) which you will use later:

```
private var shouldCalculateScrollDirection = false
private var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0
private var scrollDirection: ScrollDirection = .up
```

3) In the *scrollViewDidScroll* add the following:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // The current offset
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    // Determine the scolling direction
    if lastContentOffset > offset && shouldCalculateScrollDirection {
        scrollDirection = .down
    }
    else if lastContentOffset < offset && shouldCalculateScrollDirection {
        scrollDirection = .up
    }

    // This needs to be in the last line
    lastContentOffset = offset
}
```

4) If you have not implemented *scrollViewDidEndDragging* implement it and add these lines of code inside it:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    guard !decelerate else { return }
    shouldCalculateScrollDirection = false
}
```

5) If you have not implemented *scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating* implement it and add this line of code inside it:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    shouldCalculateScrollDirection = false
}
```

6) Finally, If you have not implemented *scrollViewWillBeginDragging* implement it and add this line of code inside it:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {    
    shouldCalculateScrollDirection = true
}
```

And if you followed all the steps above you are good to go!

You could go to wherever you want to use the direction and simply write:

```
switch scrollDirection {
case .up:
    // Do something for scollDirection up
case .down:
    // Do something for scollDirection down
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
extension UIScrollView {
    enum ScrollDirection {
        case up, down, unknown
    }
    
    var scrollDirection: ScrollDirection {
        guard let superview = superview else { return .unknown }
        return panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: superview).y > 0 ? .down : .up
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 2-4 with UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Another option, is use to use the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` that will recognize the swipe to requested direction (That will work on all views and not only on `UIScrollView`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let upGs = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleSwipes(sender:)))
        let downGs = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleSwipes(sender:)))
        
        upGs.direction = .up
        downGs.direction = .down
        
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(upGs)
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(downGs)
    }

    @objc func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        
        if (sender.direction == .up) {
            print("Up")
        }
        
        if (sender.direction == .down) {
            print("Down")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is that I have an container view with an embedded /Seguetable view. So my swipes doesnt get picked up. Any idea how I still can get them? Will accept soon

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like this:

```
fileprivate var lastContentOffset: CGPoint = .zero

func checkScrollDirection(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIScrollViewDirection {
    return lastContentOffset.y > scrollView.contentOffset.y ? .up : .down
}
```

and with scrollViewDelegate:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    switch checkScrollDirection(scrollView) {
    case .up:
        // move up
    case .down:
        // move down
    default:
        break
    }

    lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found that this is the simplest and most flexible option (it works for UICollectionView and UITableView as well).

```
override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    switch velocity {
    case _ where velocity.y < 0:
        // swipes from top to bottom of screen -> down
        trackingDirection = .down
    case _ where velocity.y > 0:
        // swipes from bottom to top of screen -> up
        trackingDirection = .up
    default: trackingDirection = .none
    }
}
```

Where this doesn't work though, is if there is 0 velocity - in which case you'll have no choice but to use the accepted answer's stored property solution.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add this method to your *view* *controller*:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
        // Move UP - Show Navigation Bar
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0) {
        // Move DOWN - Hide Navigation Bar
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift** I think the simplest and most powerful is to do like below. 
It allows you to track when direction changed and react only once when it changed.
Plus you can always access the `.lastDirection` scrolled property if you need to consult that in your code at any other stage.

```
enum WMScrollDirection {
    case Up, Down, None
}

class WMScrollView: UIScrollView {
    var lastDirection: WMScrollDirection = .None {
        didSet {
            if oldValue != lastDirection {
                // direction has changed, call your func here
            }
        }
    }

    override var contentOffset: CGPoint {
        willSet {
            if contentOffset.y > newValue.y {
                lastDirection = .Down
            }
            else {
                lastDirection = .Up
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above assumes you are only tracking up/down scrolling.
It is customizable via the enum. You could add/change to `.left` and `.right` to track any direction.

I hope this helps someone.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I made protocol to reuse Scroll Directions.

Declare these `enum` and `protocol`s.

```
enum ScrollDirection {
    case up, left, down, right, none
}

protocol ScrollDirectionDetectable {
    associatedtype ScrollViewType: UIScrollView
    var scrollView: ScrollViewType { get }
    var scrollDirection: ScrollDirection { get set }
    var lastContentOffset: CGPoint { get set }
}

extension ScrollDirectionDetectable {
    var scrollView: ScrollViewType {
        return self.scrollView
    }
}
```

Usage From `ViewController`

```
// Set ScrollDirectionDetectable which has UIScrollViewDelegate
class YourViewController: UIViewController, ScrollDirectionDetectable {
    // any types that inherit UIScrollView can be ScrollViewType
    typealias ScrollViewType = UIScrollView
    var lastContentOffset: CGPoint = .zero
    var scrollDirection: ScrollDirection = .none

}
    extension YourViewController {
        func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            // Update ScrollView direction
            if self.lastContentOffset.x > scrollView.contentOffset.x {
                scrollDirection = .left
            } else if self.lastContentOffset.x > scrollView.contentOffset.x {
                scrollDirection = .right
            }

            if self.lastContentOffset.y > scrollView.contentOffset.y {
                scrollDirection = .up
            } else if self.lastContentOffset.y < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
                scrollDirection = .down
            }
            self.lastContentOffset.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
            self.lastContentOffset.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        }
    }
```

If you want to use specific direction, just update specific `contentOffset` that you want.

Comment: Should be self.lastContentOffset.x < scrollView.contentOffset.x for the right direction

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I did. It works in almost all cases I have tried.

1. User scrolls up or down
2. User changes direction while scrolling
3. User doesn't drag any more. And scroll view continues scrolling.

> ```
>     var goingUp: Bool
>     let velocity = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.velocity(in: scrollView).y
>     /// `Velocity` is 0 when user is not dragging.
>     if (velocity == 0){
>         goingUp = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView).y < 0
>     } else {
>         goingUp = velocity < 0
>     }
> ```